# Entity framework throws exception while executing UPDATE statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an EF6 powered program that crashes on an UPDATE statement, when running for the first time.
I tried renaming the columns via data annotations (I didn't test fluid API, since it should result in the same database). I also looked at the class visibilities, but they didn't change since the last time the program worked and thus can be ruled out.
I've looked at it for the better part of a day, but cannot find the error. The database looks sound to me and the code compiles without problem. Also any `update-database` statements are executed without an exception.

Here is the stack-trace:

```
System.Data.DataException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
       bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
       bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
       bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
       bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
       bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
       bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
       bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path)
       bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path)
       bei System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include[T](IQueryable`1 source, String path)
       bei System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include[T,TProperty](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 path)
       bei RpgTools.Characters.CharacterRepository.FindAll() in e:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\RpgTools\Modules\Characters\CharacterRepository.cs:Zeile 88.
       bei RpgTools.CharacterPresenter.ViewModels.CharactersViewModel.LoadCharacters() in e:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\RpgTools\Modules\CharacterPresenter\ViewModels\CharactersViewModel.cs:Zeile 169.
  InnerException: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException
       HResult=-2146233087
       Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       Source=EntityFramework
       StackTrace:
            bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
            bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
            bei System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
            bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
            bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.SeedDatabase()
            bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
            bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
            bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
            bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
            bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
            bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
            bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
            bei System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update()
            bei System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
            bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
            bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
       InnerException: System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException
            HResult=-2146233087
            Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
            Source=EntityFramework
            StackTrace:
                 bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
                 bei System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
                 bei System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
                 bei System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
                 bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
                 bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
                 bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
                 bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
                 bei System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
                 bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
                 bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
                 bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
            InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
                 HResult=-2146232060
                 Message=The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Characters.Characters_Characters.Appearances_AppearanceId". The conflict occurred in database "RpgTools", table "Characters.Appearances", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
                 Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
                 ErrorCode=-2146232060
                 Class=16
                 LineNumber=1
                 Number=547
                 Procedure=""
                 Server=(LocalDb)\mssqllocaldb
                 State=0
                 StackTrace:
                      bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
                      bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
                      bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
                      bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
                      bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
                      bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
                      bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
                      bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
                      bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                      bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
                      bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
                      bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
                      bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                      bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
                      bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
                 InnerException:
```

Here is the method that throws the exception. The exception is thrown on at the include statement. I might add, that the class for the following two methods is `internal sealed`

```
/// <inheritdoc />
public IDictionaryRange<Guid, Character> FindAll()
{
    IDataContainer<ICollection<CharacterItem>> data = this.CreateContainer<ICollection<CharacterItem>>(
        this.Characters.Include(c => c.Appearance).Include(c => c.Metadata).ToList(),
        this.Culture);

        return this.bulkReadConverter.Convert(data);
}

private IDataContainer<TData> CreateContainer<TData>(TData data, CultureInfo culture = null, DateTimeOffset? date = null)
{
    return new DataContainer<TData>
    {
        Content = data,
        Culture = culture,
        Date = date
    };
}
```

These are the classes that represent my data:

```
[Table("Character")]
internal class CharacterItem
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Nickname { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Biography { get; set; }

    public string Motto { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Guid PortraitsId { get; set; }

    public PortraitItem Portrait { get; set; }

    public Guid MetadataId { get; set; }

    public CharacterMetadataItem Metadata { get; set; }

    public Guid AppearancesId { get; set; }

    public AppearanceItem Appearance { get; set; }

    public Guid OriginId { get; set; }
}

[Table("Appearances")]
internal sealed class AppearanceItem
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Genders Gender { get; set; }

    public int Height { get; set; }

    public int Weight { get; set; }

    public string SkinColour { get; set; }

    public string EyeColour { get; set; }

    public string SpecialFeatures { get; set; }

    public string HairColour { get; set; }

    public string LipColour { get; set; }
}
```

And here are the SQL statements for the DB schema.

```
CREATE TABLE [Characters].[Character] (
    [Id]            UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Name]          NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [Nickname]      NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [Title]         NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [Description]   NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [Biography]     NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [Motto]         NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [Age]           INT              NOT NULL,
    [PortraitsId]   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [MetadataId]    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [AppearancesId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [OriginId]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Appearance_Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [Portrait_Id]   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Characters.Character] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Characters.Character_Characters.Appearances_Appearance_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Appearance_Id]) REFERENCES [Characters].[Appearances] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Characters.Character_Characters.Metadata_MetadataId] FOREIGN KEY ([MetadataId]) REFERENCES [Characters].[Metadata] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Characters.Character_Characters.Portraits_Portrait_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Portrait_Id]) REFERENCES [Characters].[Portraits] ([Id])
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_MetadataId]
    ON [Characters].[Character]([MetadataId] ASC);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Appearance_Id]
    ON [Characters].[Character]([Appearance_Id] ASC);


    GO
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Portrait_Id]
        ON [Characters].[Character]([Portrait_Id] ASC);

CREATE TABLE [Characters].[Appearances] (
    [Id]              UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Gender]          INT              NOT NULL,
    [Height]          INT              NOT NULL,
    [Weight]          INT              NOT NULL,
    [SkinColour]      NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [EyeColour]       NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [SpecialFeatures] NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [HairColour]      NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    [LipColour]       NVARCHAR (MAX)   NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Characters.Appearances] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

---

As per suggestion of John Castleman I changed the Schema initialisation, which was previously done by FluidAPI to DataAnnotations. Then I added another migration and applied another `update-database` now I get an error when I run the command, not just when starting the program.
Below is the error and my migrations:

This is the stack trace with the -verbose switch enabled. I had to delete the old one, since I reached the character limit.

```
Using StartUp project 'Main'.
Using NuGet project 'Characters'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'RpgTools' (DataSource: (LocalDb)\mssqllocaldb, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Characters.Character_Characters.Metadata_MetadataId". The conflict occurred in database "RpgTools", table "Characters.Metadata", column 'Id'.
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
```

Migrations:

```
public partial class v0_1_0 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "Characters.Character",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(),
                    Nickname = c.String(),
                    Title = c.String(),
                    Description = c.String(),
                    Biography = c.String(),
                    Motto = c.String(),
                    Age = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    PortraitsId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    MetadataId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    AppearancesId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    OriginId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Appearance_Id = c.Guid(),
                    Portrait_Id = c.Guid(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("Characters.Appearances", t => t.Appearance_Id)
            .ForeignKey("Characters.Metadata", t => t.MetadataId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("Characters.Portraits", t => t.Portrait_Id)
            .Index(t => t.MetadataId)
            .Index(t => t.Appearance_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Portrait_Id);

        CreateTable(
            "Characters.Appearances",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Gender = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Height = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Weight = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    SkinColour = c.String(),
                    EyeColour = c.String(),
                    SpecialFeatures = c.String(),
                    HairColour = c.String(),
                    LipColour = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "Characters.Metadata",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Tags = c.String(),
                    VoiceActor = c.String(),
                    Occurrences = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "Characters.Portraits",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Data = c.Binary(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("Characters.Character", "Portrait_Id", "Characters.Portraits");
        DropForeignKey("Characters.Character", "MetadataId", "Characters.Metadata");
        DropForeignKey("Characters.Character", "Appearance_Id", "Characters.Appearances");
        DropIndex("Characters.Character", new[] { "Portrait_Id" });
        DropIndex("Characters.Character", new[] { "Appearance_Id" });
        DropIndex("Characters.Character", new[] { "MetadataId" });
        DropTable("Characters.Portraits");
        DropTable("Characters.Metadata");
        DropTable("Characters.Appearances");
        DropTable("Characters.Character");
    }
}

public partial class v0_1_1 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

The funny thing is: Even though the second migration is empty the `update-database` command fails. The first migration runs just fine, but then I get an error when starting the program.
As additional information here is the constructor of my repository and the configuration file for it.

```
internal CharacterRepository(IConverter<CharacterItem, Character> characterReadConverter, IConverter<Character, CharacterItem> characterWriteConverter)
    : base("name=RpgTools")
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<CharacterRepository, Configuration>(true));
    this.Characters = this.Set<CharacterItem>();

    this.readConverter = new DataConverter<CharacterItem, Character>(characterReadConverter);
    this.bulkReadConverter = new DictionaryRangeConverter<CharacterItem, Guid, Character>(characterReadConverter, c => c.Id);
    this.writeConverter = new DataConverter<Character, CharacterItem>(characterWriteConverter);
}

internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CharacterRepository>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(CharacterRepository context)
    {
        Guid[] ids =
        {
            new Guid("13cbbdc8-d2e6-4a9a-9525-fa9043a53082"),
            new Guid("3a34fd9b-a6e3-4567-af83-840ddf4417ba"),
            new Guid("b1256f9f-8a35-416a-8f22-6be91ffb4041"),
            new Guid("2e24283d-1ba0-4cc7-b49c-975937e8512c"),
            new Guid("2f66d513-1839-4a26-be7e-39243d6807cf")
        };

        CharacterItem char1 = new CharacterItem
        {
            Age = 22,
            Appearance = new AppearanceItem
            {
                EyeColour = "Green",
                Gender = Genders.Female,
                HairColour = "Red",
                Height = 188,
                Id = ids[1],
                LipColour = "red",
                SkinColour = "fair",
                Weight = 76
            },
            Id = ids[0],
            Metadata = new CharacterMetadataItem
            {
                Id = ids[2],
                Occurrences = string.Empty,
                Tags = "Female; Protagonist"
            },
            Motto = null,
            Name = "Sarah Fenix",
            Nickname = string.Empty,
            Portrait = null,
            Description = "Ravia Hagen's spouse",
            Title = string.Empty
        };

        var char2 = new CharacterItem
        {
            Age = 22,
            Appearance = new AppearanceItem
            {
                EyeColour = "Green",
                Gender = Genders.Female,
                HairColour = "Red",
                Height = 188,
                Id = ids[4],
                LipColour = "red",
                SkinColour = "fair",
                Weight = 76
            },
            Id = ids[3],
            Metadata = new CharacterMetadataItem
            {
                Id = ids[5],
                Occurrences = string.Empty,
                Tags = "Female; Protagonist",
                VoiceActor = string.Empty
            },
            Motto = null,
            Name = "Ravia Hagen",
            Nickname = string.Empty,
            Portrait = null,
            Description = "Sarah Fenix's spouse",
            Title = string.Empty
        };

        context.Characters.AddOrUpdate(c => c.Id, char1, char2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, You stated that this was failing on an update, the error *definitely* shows a problem with an update, yet you posted a `FindAll()` method that doesn't call `SaveChanges()` at all and say the error occurs on an `Include` (which has nothing to do with updates)?

Comment: Yep. That is what confuses me too. I call the `FindAll() ` method, which only retrieves data, yet an UPDATE statement fails.

Comment: based on the message `An exception occurred while initializing the database.`, my best guess is that there is a pending migration that is trying to do data-motion, but is encountering issues.  However, you said `Update-Database` doesn't choke; is that targeting the same database?

Comment: That is strange, I admit. However I have some new additional information. Now I cannot even run the `update-database` command. See my initial question for more details.

Comment: ok, so this is *definitely* a data-motion issue.  You have changed the model in some way which is requiring the data to be moved into a new table with a different schema.  we can narrow down the cause, starting with running `update-database -verbose` and seeing where that leads.

Comment: based on the update, it appears that it's failing at the `Seed` method.  Is your `Seed` trying to insert data that already exists?

Comment: I'm personally not an expert on `Seed` methods, but I can see here that you are definitely telling EF to create new `AppearanceItem` instances but assigning them pre-existing `Id` attributes.  I don't think `AddOrUpdate` analyses the state of the navigation properties to determine if they need add or update as well, I think it **always** assumes the navigation properties should be add.

Comment: I'm assigning them pre generated Ids, since my program stores the unique ID as a GUID and not as an auto incrementing integer. If I would leave that out, I'd get the standard empty GUID in my database. I'll run the update-database -verbose commmand as soon as I get home.

Comment: but that's exactly my point; those ids already exist in the database but they are being attempted to add again because navigation properties are not considered update.

Comment: That is strange, because all the time I did it this way. So that I understand it correctly: Because I added the Id's in the first seed and then run an `update-database` command EF tries to re-add the ids to the database and then fails? If so, how could I solve this? Switching away from GUIDs is a bit of a hassle, since the program can get the data from multiples sources.

Comment: I ran the `update-database` command with the verbose switch again. The new stack trace is now located at the place of the old one (second from top)

Comment: `The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Characters.Character_Characters.Metadata_MetadataId". The conflict occurred in database "RpgTools", table "Characters.Metadata", column 'Id'.`.  This still tells me that those `Id` are already in the database and can't be added again, but this time it appears to be the `Characters.Metadata`.

Comment: For testing I commented out the Ids in my seed method. It still does not run, since I now get an update error, that tells me, that the empty GUID already in the database. This is something I thought would happen, since the database does not automatically set a unique ID (for various program related reasons). Therefore I have to set the ID in my seed method.

Comment: right, but you can't use the *same* ids every time you run the migration.  Again, I stated earlier that I'm not really an expert in seed methods, but this seed method doesn't look like it will work.  even though your `character` is being checked for existence from `AddOrUpdate`, it's navigation properties are not, so `Metadata`, `Appearances`, etc. are being tried to insert again, even if they already exist, causing a conflict.

Comment: That would make sense, yes. I'll change my seed method to accomondate for this fact. Thanks!

Comment: good luck, I hope you find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `[Table("Character", Schema = "Characters")]` or just `[Table("Characters.Character")]` should work, too. Otherwise, EF is trying to use `[dbo].[Character]`.

If the schema difference has been recently introduced, it's likely the root of the problem.

**Edit, based on question update:**

Not sure how you're getting past the compiler throwing an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` – sometimes EF implicitly null coalesces? – but considering your InnerException has to do with `Metadata.Id`, I consider it suspect that you're using a value off the end of your array to initialize this property (array of 5 means indices 0 - 4, so your `ids[5]` is out-of-bounds).

Chances are, EF is doing something "magical" for you here rather than throwing ... however, something about that is apparently causing the subsequent FK violation.

You probably had these in a slightly different order when you originally posted, because it had been Appearances.Id that was at fault.

Comment: I always thought schema had to be done with Fluid API and thus I did it there. But I changed it to your suggestion (I like it more, since it keeps my repository clean of such a trivial thing). But now I get a similar error in a different place, see my question for details.

Comment: Oh my bad. I truncated the array of Id's and the seed method a bit. My data generation has an array of 20 GUIDs and five characters. I thought that might be a tad too much for an SO question. Be sure however, that the truncated data has the exact same structure.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the update itself but the fact that the record you are trying to update would break a foreign key constraint.

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Characters.Characters_Characters.Appearances_AppearanceId". The
>   conflict occurred in database "RpgTools", table
>   "Characters.Appearances", column 'Id'.

We don't have your DB schema so you will have to search your database to find out what is the `FK_Characters.Characters_Characters.Appearances_AppearanceId` about an then make sure the record you are trying to update is "legit" with the FK constraint.

Comment: The thing is: I don't update any data. I only retrieve data from the database and that is my problem: The update-database command executed from the Package manager console runs perfectly fine and inserts data into the database. Yet when I retrieve data I get the error. I added the Schema to my question to give more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem but I figured it out. I tried to insert into Table_1 one object which had some properties and on of these properties was `FOREIGN KEY` that refers to the `PRIMARY KEY` in another table (Table_2) in this database.

But this another Table_2 was empty. So I had to create one row (one object) in Table_2 with primary key. This `PRIMARY KEY` had to be equal to `FOREIGN KEY` or property of object I wanted to insert into Table_1.

Because when you want to insert some objects into table which have foreign key to another table, SQL server checks if another table has some object/s which this foreign key. If not nothing happened.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a data problem :

> Message=The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint
>   "FK_Characters.Characters_Characters.Appearances_AppearanceId". The
>   conflict occurred in database "RpgTools", table
>   "Characters.Appearances", column 'Id'.